# Can't get Dynamic image URL work in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show an img with the Django dynamic url, but I cant get the dynamic url right

**url.py**

```
    path('Obra/<int:id>/', views.detalle_obra, name="detalle_obra"),
```

**work-single.html**

```
 ...<img src="{{object.img.url}}"
```

**views.py**

```
def works(request, id):
    obj = Work.objects.get(id=id)
    context= {
        'object':obj
    }
    return render(request, 'works-single.html',context)
```

when I render the template this image pop on the console:

Not Found: /Obra/1/static/mySiteWork/img/uploads/Proyecto Obra Cerrillos/P5230031.jpg

I don't know why is showing the "/Obra/1/". When I print {{object.img.url}} it will only show me the "static path static/mySiteWork/img/uploads/Proyecto Obra Cerrillos/P5230031.jpg"

the static files works fine in the rest of templates

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:
I change this on the html template:

```
<img src="{{object.img.url}}">
```

for this:

```
<img src="/{{object.img.url}}">
```

Not sure why... but it works fine

Comment: In Django 3.x there is no default MEDIA_URL any more. Which means it makes a relative path. You **have** to define a MEDIA_URL in your settings.py. Both MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL should start and end with a `/`. You don't have one or more of these conditions done properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the value of the `MEDIA_URL` variable from the settings file. The argument `upload_to` from the forms is relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL`. Django calculates the path to a user uploaded file as `MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL/file_url`.

Seems that MEDIA_URL in your settings is set to "Obra/1".

Comment: Hi, the same value on MEDIA_URL works within others templates, it's when I try to send an argument with the value '1' in the url.py when the path stop working. Thanks